# Firebase Web: Multiple database instance firebase.database(url) Error: Argument of type '""' is not assignable to parameter of type 'App'

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to access multiple firebase database instance in Angular WebApp. Here is my code:

```
firebase.database("https://<url for secondary db instance>")
```

I am getting the error saying:

> database only accepts "app" as a parameter in database(app:App)

But in firebase documentation it says that: `firebase.database('https://<url for secondary db instance>');`. Here is the reference of [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding).

In package.json version firebase version ^5.0.4

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I have found a google group discussion saying it is not supported yet. Here is the link https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/firebase-talk/SQu9ce9X9uI/Zo66vGZFCwAJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the reference doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database), `firebase.database()` only accepts an app instance, not a string. I put in a fix for the docs that should roll out shortly. Here's the correct way to do this in JavaScript:

```
// init
const app1 = firebase.initializeApp({
  databaseURL: "https://testapp-1234-1.firebaseio.com"
});

const app2 = firebase.initializeApp({
  databaseURL: "https://testapp-1234-2.firebaseio.com"
}, 'app2');

// Get the default database instance for an app1
const database1 = firebase.database();

// Get a database instance for app2
const database2 = firebase.database(app2);

// This also works obviously
// const database1 = firebase.database(app1);
```

Comment: Thanks Kato. And there might be  a typo in firebase references for web refFromURL. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Database#refFromURL

Comment: Looks like refFromURL is okay. It takes a string, but you'll note that it mentions that the domain must match. So must be for the right db instance.